# How do I select to send email to individual users in my workflow?

Tags: workflow, email, user, notifications

I have a workflow connected to a list with a column named "Names Assigned" where multiple people can be selected (people picker).

My workflow is designed to send an email to "CurrentItem : Names Assigned" but it sends an email to ALL users instead of sending separate, private emails to users assigned.

How can I get the emails to send out to each user individually?

Thank you, 
Madeline

Comment: Is this a 2010 or 2013 style workflow?

Comment: a 2010 workflow, mike. I'm really struggling here/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need add a step to make sure the assigned to value is not null before firing off the email.

You can find more details on this here. [TechNet How to Send E-Mail to Specific Assigned To](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/c8c34a45-b51f-42d9-a5c9-6b654e703c87/reusable-workflow-how-to-send-email-to-specific-assigned-to?forum=sharepointgenerallegacy)

Edit:
So looking at SP 2010, it appears that this might be a known limitation. While there are workarounds, they are either 3rd party tools or require custom development of the workflow in order to loop through the list and send the email individually to the members of said list (Name Assigned). So unfortunately, you would need to build a script to look at the list, determine who is listed, do the mailto, then proceed to the next person. It is not something you can do straight OOTB. Alternatively, you could set the field to BCC as opposed to To, so that no one could see the other people receiving the same email from the OOTB solution.

Good luck!

Comment: Hello and thank you for your input Chris. Yes, this sends out an email to everyone in the "assigned to" column at *the same time* I want an individual email to go out to everyone separately not together. 

thanks for the input!
madeline

Comment: Ah. Sorry for misunderstanding. I will see what I can find and get back if I find anything better.

Comment: Created an edit that gives some basic info.

Comment: This seems like it should work, however it is asking me to fill in the "TO" line, even when my BCC line is filled in with the "names assigned". Any suggestions? I'm going to meddle around with this today.

Comment: HEY chris! It good now. I just put the title of the event in the "TO" to protect the privacy of people. Appreciate the help.

madeline

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use BCC feature of SPD 2010 workflow.
Using BCC, all the recipients in the BCC will receive separate email without notifying about who else has received other than BCC persons.

Reference: [How to use BCC in SPD 2010 workflow](https://sharepointlibrarian.com/2017/08/23/use-bcc-field-in-sharepoint-designer-workflow-email-actions/)

Comment: thank you, you and chris were very helpful. Good to go, now. 

Thanks again. Madeline